# Problem upgrading Magento from 2.0.2 to 2.0.5

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, magento-2.0.2

When trying to upgrade using Web Interface, the readiness check fail with this error:

> PHP Settings Check Need Help? PHP Documentation Your PHP Version is
>   5.6.20, but always_populate_raw_post_data = 0. $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated from PHP 5.6 onwards and will be removed in PHP 7.0. This
>   will stop the installer from running. Please open your php.ini file
>   and set always_populate_raw_post_data to -1. If you need more help
>   please call your hosting provider.

That is a nonsense since that variable is already -1:

[image]

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

It's barely noticeable, but at the top of the image you posted, it appears the version is 5.6.13.  Since the wizard is saying you're running 5.6.20, it seems that your Magento install is pointing to a different php install.

Comment: you are completely right. For some reason, PHP was updated automatically to version 5.6.20 using yum, but strangely, all websites continue using 5.6.13. However, magento update uses cron to do the update, so it uses PHP 5.6.20. Do you think this is the problem even if cron uss 5.6.20?

Comment: it appears that way.  you need to check the 'always_populate_raw_post_data' setting for your php 5.6.20 install.  I believe cron uses the cli version of php.  If you have ssh access, you can run 'php -i | grep always_populate_raw_post_data' to see what the setting is for php cli.

Comment: when using "php -i" command, appears that variable is -1 and PHP version is 5.6.13. I don't know why Magento installation is thinking I have 5.6.20.

Comment: If you're hosting allows, different php versions can be specified for each site/domain you have.  This is usually possible to change in CPanel or WHM. Here is a link with instructions : [link]http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php/how-to-change-the-php-version-your-account-uses

Comment: This is a propietary control panel called  Ferozo.  It allows multiple versions but the last is 5.6.13. I don't know why 5.6.20 is being detected.

Comment: Sounds like the path to php 5.6.20 needs to be added to $PATH.  Your hosting company may have to do that.

Comment: It is a VPS... I have full cotrol over it..... I have removed PHP 5.6.20 and it is not listed already when I issue "rpm -qa" command. Version 5.6.20 is a ghost.